# Exclude entries in custom agenda views based on Level

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to configure a custom agenda view. I'd like to search through an `.org` file by matching tags, but then only show the top-level headline. I.e., suppose my org-file looks like this.

```
* Heading 1 :Target:
** Subheading a
* Heading 2
```

If I match tags in my agenda view, it will list both Heading 1 and Subheading a. I'd like to only include the top-level headline in my agenda view.

I've looked at the org-mode documentation, and I've found the `Level` specification (see [orgmode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html)). But I can't figure out how to make it work. This may just be my being a novice when it comes to LISP programming.